# Is metro/store app destop or web based

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I know what is metro app (just did some research) my question is where metro app runs. By my understanding :

- Detktop app: running on your local machine with .net framework, and present data to user, you can launch/close it.
- Web app: Publishing on IIS server, running from server render html to client, user can send request and get result.

Now, Metro app: is it just distributed on windows store, user can download/install it and run from local as same as desktop? or run from store, render something to user like web? or maybe some new working styles, can user close it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a metro app. I'm pretty sure you mean a Windows Store App. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metro Style App was a working name before Microsoft settled on Windows Store Apps.

Windows Store Apps just like desktop apps run on local machine, but are often architected in more modern ways where the app would often connect to web services or push notifications that run in a data center. The UI though usually runs on local machine even if it is written in html/js with winjs.

The biggest difference is distribution - web apps run on the server so you only need to navigate to them in your browser to run the latest version. Desktop apps need to be installed - either with xcopy-style install, Windows installer or perhaps the ClickOnce technology. Store apps are distributed through the store which makes them easier to install and update than desktop apps as well as monetize, but are sandboxed (have limited access to local machine resources) for security.